# div going outside container when I add padding

Tags: html, css

my right side button is pushing outside of its container when I add padding to it. How do I fix this?
Note that I'm also using bootstrap, please check codepen.

https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/rNarKgR

```
<div class="head">
    <nav class="container-fluid test-one">
        <div class="row parent">
            <div class="col logo"> 
                <span class="nav-left-text">west end</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col logo"> 
                <a href="" class="register-btn">register</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

```
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.nav-left-text {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.563em;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.logo {
    text-align: center;
}

.register-btn {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 0.813em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border: solid white 1px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `col-sm-6` instead of `col`?

Answer (score 1):

you are not using proper classes but use this code this is proper used of bootstarp class

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,400&display=swap');
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        
        body {
            font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
            background-color: rgb(197, 163, 163);
        }
        /*****************************
NAVBAR
*****************************/
        
        .nav-left-text {
            color: white;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 1.563em;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
        }
        
        .register-btn {
            color: white;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 0.813em;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            border: solid white 1px;
            padding: 12px 20px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <nav>
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <div class="col">
                                <span class="nav-left-text">west end</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col text-right">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="register-btn">register</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```